# 802.1x and use Google G Suite Directory as LDAP

Tags: wireless, radius, ieee-802.1x

Has anyone managed to authenticate yours to the network via 802.1x using Google Directory? I have a case where whole company is using Google Apps and G-Suite with a custom domain and they would like to access wireless network without setting addition LDAP directory. Wireless equipment is aerohive (so radius server is already build-in). Any hints on this topic will be helpful ..

Comment: Welcome to NE, we hope you will both contribute to and learn from this community. I know before Google provided an LDAP service, I used OSC Radiator and Google IMAP over TLS to authenticate. I haven't ever set up the Aerohive RADIUS server so do not know what it is capable of doing.

Comment: I am also trying to use "Cloud ID Secure LDAP" + FreeRadius + Cisco2504 to authenticate user in 802.1x. But until now it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google have just released [Secure LDAP](https://support.google.com/cloudidentity/answer/9048516) which does what you want. Note you'll need to set add Cloud Identity to your G-Suite domain. I don't know if you'll be able to get Aerohive to talk directly to it, or if you'll need to put FreeRADIUS in between.

Other existing paid options include [JumpCloud](https://jumpcloud.com) and [Foxpass](https://www.foxpass.com).

Comment: Yeah, I can Image there is a need for radius in between. Aerohive devices already include buildin FreeRADIUS.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is available in G Suite Enterprise, Cloud Identity Premium and G Suite for Education. If you have G Suite Basic or Business, you can add Cloud Identity Premium on top of existing license or upgrade to G Suite Enterprise

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I managed to authenticate the network via 802.1x using Cloud ID Secure LDAP. 
It was `Cisco2504 + FreeRADIUS + Cloud ID Premium`.

At the end, Authentication Protocol I used in Android was `802.1x EAP-TTLS/PAP`.

I think that because `Cloud ID Secure LDAP` doesn't provide `ntPassword` attribute, only way to authenticate is using `PAP` not `CHAP`, `MSCHAPv2`.